# Processing multiple forms from an only template

Tags: forms, go

I have two forms into a template, how can I identify every html form in order
to process it into my handler?
Is possible get the form name in the post handler code?
I'm using nosurf, therefore I must generate and check the 
token in the same request, maybe I'm doing wrong..

```
    <form action="/form" method="post" name="form1">
         <label class="control-label">Set A</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="my" name="my">
            </div>
      <div style="display:none;">
      <input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="{{.token}}">
      </div>            
    </form>

    <form action="/form" method="post" name="form2">
         <label class="control-label">Set thing</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="thing" name="thing">
            </div>
      <div style="display:none;">
      <input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="{{.token}}">
      </div>            
    </form>
```

My Handler

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method{
    case "GET":
        data:=map[string]interface{}{
            "key":nosurf.Token(req),
        }
        if err := renderTemplate(w, "base", data); err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }

    case "POST":
        // how?
        if r.FormValue("my"){}
        ...
        if r.FormValue("thing"){}
        ...

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is possible get the form name in the post handler code?

I don't think that's possible, but you can send the form name in another hidden input field.